# Linq query to select only common items in two lists

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have to lists:

```
Dim ListA as List (of MyClass)
Dim ListB as List (of MyClass)
```

`MyClass` includes fields `A, B , C, D`

I want to derive a list that includes only common items based on comparison only of field `A`.   `.Intersect` returns 0 count list even when there are common records (probably because MyClass doesn't implement compare method).  Also, Is there a way to do this in VB.Net?

Comment: Try `Join` on the common properties, You could still use intersect with an equality comparer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Linq Join on the common properties

```
Dim ListA As List (Of SomeClass)
Dim ListB As List (Of SomeClass)
'...
'Assuming both lists are initialized and populated
Dim ListC As List (Of SomeClass) = (From itemA In ListA 
                                    Join itemB In ListB 
                                    On itemA.A Equals itemB.A 
                                    Select itemA).ToList()
```

Comment: I used `where itemA.A=itemB.A` and it worked fine. The issue was that I was filling these lists in a loop starting out with a blank initial list and that was causing the final list to be blank.